# Convert c-order index into f-order index in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find a solution to the following problem. I have an index in C-order and I need to convert it into F-order.

**To explain simply my problem, here is an example:**

---

Let's say we have a matrix `x` as:

```
x = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)
print(x)

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Then the **flattened matrix in C order is:**

```
flat_c = x.ravel()
print(flat_c)

array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Now, the value `3` is at the `2nd position` of the `flat_c` vector i.e. `flat_c[2] is 3`.

**If I would flatten the matrix `x` using the F-order**, I would have:

```
flat_f = x.ravel(order='f')

array([1, 3, 2, 4])
```

Now, the value `3` is at the `1st position` of the `flat_f` vector i.e. `flat_f[1] is 3`.

**I am trying to find a way to get the F-order index knowing the dimension of the matrix and the corresponding index in C-order.**

I tried using `np.unravel_index` but this function returns the matrix positions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a combination of [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) and [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) for a ndarray supported solution. Hence, given array shape `s` of input array `a` and c-order index `c_idx`, it would be -

```
s = a.shape
f_idx = np.ravel_multi_index(np.unravel_index(c_idx,s)[::-1],s[::-1])
```

So, the idea is pretty simple. Use `np.unravel_index` to get c-based indices in n-dim, then get flattened-linear index in fortran order by using `np.ravel_multi_index` on flipped shape and those flipped n-dim indices to simulate fortran behavior.

Sample runs on `2D` -

```
In [321]: a
Out[321]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

In [322]: s = a.shape

In [323]: c_idx = 6

In [324]: np.ravel_multi_index(np.unravel_index(c_idx,s)[::-1],s[::-1])
Out[324]: 4

In [325]: c_idx = 12

In [326]: np.ravel_multi_index(np.unravel_index(c_idx,s)[::-1],s[::-1])
Out[326]: 8
```

Sample run on 3D array -

```
In [336]: a
Out[336]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])

In [337]: s = a.shape

In [338]: c_idx = 21

In [339]: np.ravel_multi_index(np.unravel_index(c_idx,s)[::-1],s[::-1])
Out[339]: 9

In [340]: a.ravel('F')[9]
Out[340]: 21
```

Comment: this is really close to what I need however, not exactly what I am looking for. For example, in my example using `x`, if I set `c_order_index = 1` that corresponds to the element `2` in c-order, then the output of the code returns `1` and not `2` as it should

Comment: @seralouk The question title and text reads - `"I am trying to find a way to get the F-order index knowing the dimension of the matrix and the corresponding index in C-order."`. So, are you looking to the get the index or the element?

Comment: Yes, the index of the element.

Comment: the below answer by @Nachiket seems to be working but ideally I need something involving numpy so that it can handle more generic cases.

Comment: @seralouk Yup was a bug indeed. Check out edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your matrix is of shape `(nrow,ncol)`. Then the 1D index when unraveled in `C` style for the `(irow,icol)` entry is given by

`idxc = ncol*irow + icol`

In the above equation, you know `idxc`. Then,

`icol = idxc % ncol`

Now you can find `irow`

`irow = (idxc - icol) / ncol`

Now you know both `irow` and `icol`. You can use them to get the `F` index. I think the `F` index will be given by

`idxf = nrow*icol + irow`

Please double-check my math, I might have got something wrong...

For the 3D case, if your array has dimensions `[n1][n2][n3]`, then the unraveled C-index for `[i1][i2][i3]` is

`idxc = n2*n3*i1 + n3*i2+i3`

Using modulo operations similar to the 2D case, we can recover `i1,i2,i3` and then convert to unraveled `F` index, i.e.

```
n3*i2 + i3 = idxc % (n2*n3)
i3 = (n3*i2+i3) % n3
i2 = ((n3*i2+i3) - i3) /n3
i1 = (idxc-(n3+i2+i3)) /(n2*n3)
```

`F` index would be:

```
idxf = i1 + n1*i2 +n1*n2*i3
```

Please check my math.

Comment: this seems to be working - how can I extend this for cases where my matrix `x` is a 3D array ?

Comment: so how do you define `i1,i2,i3`?

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases you may also get away with transposing and ravelling the array:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2 * 2).reshape(2, 2)

print(x)
# [[0 1]
#  [2 3]]
print(x.ravel())
# [0 1 2 3]
print(x.transpose().ravel())
# [0 2 1 3]

x = np.arange(2 * 3 * 4).reshape(2, 3, 4)

print(x)
# [[[ 0  1  2  3]
#   [ 4  5  6  7]
#   [ 8  9 10 11]]

#  [[12 13 14 15]
#   [16 17 18 19]
#   [20 21 22 23]]]
print(x.ravel())
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
print(x.transpose().ravel())
# [ 0 12  4 16  8 20  1 13  5 17  9 21  2 14  6 18 10 22  3 15  7 19 11 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but it might help somebody in the future. Without any help from numpy, any index can be converted, regardless of the dimension, like this:

```
## Create a file: fortran2cc2fortran.py

def calculate_nested_index_f_order(flat_index, array_shape):
    r"""
    Calculate the nested index of a given flat index in Fortran order.

    Parameters:
    - flat_index (int): The flat index to be converted.
    - array_shape (tuple): Shape of the original array.

    Returns:
    - list: List of indices in Fortran order corresponding to the flat index.
    """
    indlistlen = len(array_shape)
    doneindex = []
    geht = flat_index
    for zahlx in range(indlistlen):
        geht1 = geht // array_shape[zahlx]
        bleibt = geht % array_shape[zahlx]
        geht = geht1
        doneindex.append(bleibt)
    return doneindex


def calculate_flat_index_f(nested_index, array_shape):
    r"""
    Calculate the flat index from a given nested index in Fortran order.

    Parameters:
    - nested_index (list): Nested index in Fortran order.
    - array_shape (tuple): Shape of the original array.

    Returns:
    - int: Flat index corresponding to the nested index in Fortran order.
    """
    maxind = len(nested_index) - 1
    array_shape_len = len(array_shape)
    wholeindex = nested_index[maxind]
    for y in range(maxind):
        tmpda = nested_index[y]
        for x in range(y + 1, array_shape_len):
            tmpda = tmpda * array_shape[x]
        wholeindex = wholeindex + tmpda
    return wholeindex


def calculate_flat_index_c(nested_index, array_shape):
    r"""
    Calculate the flat index from a given nested index in C order.

    Parameters:
    - nested_index (list): Nested index in C order.
    - array_shape (tuple): Shape of the original array.

    Returns:
    - int: Flat index corresponding to the nested index in C order.
    """
    maxind = len(nested_index) - 1
    wholeindex = 0
    for y in range(maxind, -1, -1):
        tmpda = nested_index[y]
        for x in range(y - 1, -1, -1):
            tmpda = tmpda * array_shape[x]
        wholeindex = wholeindex + tmpda
    return wholeindex


def calculate_nested_index_c_order(flat_index, array_shape):
    r"""
    Calculate the nested index of a given flat index in C order.

    Parameters:
    - flat_index (int): The flat index to be converted.
    - array_shape (tuple): Shape of the original array.

    Returns:
    - list: List of indices in C order corresponding to the flat index.
    """
    indlistlen = len(array_shape)
    doneindex = []
    geht = flat_index
    for zahlx in range(indlistlen - 1, -1, -1):
        geht1 = geht // array_shape[zahlx]
        bleibt = geht % array_shape[zahlx]
        geht = geht1
        doneindex.insert(0, bleibt)
    return doneindex


def convert_c_to_f_index(c_index, array_shape):
    r"""
    Convert C order to Fortran order and return the corresponding nested index.

    Parameters:
    - c_index (list): Nested index in C order.
    - array_shape (tuple): Shape of the original array.

    Returns:
    - list: Nested index in Fortran order corresponding to the C order index.
    """
    flatind = calculate_flat_index_f(nested_index=c_index, array_shape=array_shape)
    return calculate_nested_index_f_order(flat_index=flatind, array_shape=array_shape)


def convert_f_to_c_index(f_index, array_shape):
    r"""
    Convert Fortran order to C order and return the corresponding nested index.

    Parameters:
    - f_index (list): Nested index in Fortran order.
    - array_shape (tuple): Shape of the original array.

    Returns:
    - list: Nested index in C order corresponding to the Fortran order index.
    """
    flatind = calculate_flat_index_c(nested_index=f_index, array_shape=array_shape)
    return calculate_nested_index_c_order(flat_index=flatind, array_shape=array_shape)
```

### Test

```
import numpy as np
from fortran2cc2fortran import (
    convert_f_to_c_index,
    convert_c_to_f_index,
    calculate_nested_index_c_order,
    calculate_flat_index_c,
    calculate_nested_index_f_order,
    calculate_flat_index_f,
)

indlist = [10, 5, 4, 2, 3]
listex = np.ascontiguousarray(
    np.copy(np.arange(np.product(indlist)).reshape(tuple(indlist)))
)
liste = listex.ravel(order="F")
liste2 = listex.ravel(order="C")
if not liste.flags["F_CONTIGUOUS"]:
    liste = np.asfortranarray(liste)
if not liste2.flags["C_CONTIGUOUS"]:
    liste2 = np.ascontiguousarray(liste2)
for l in range(len(liste)):
    value = liste[l]
    value2 = liste2[l]
    c_order_index = calculate_nested_index_c_order(
        flat_index=l, array_shape=listex.shape
    )
    flatindex1 = calculate_flat_index_f(
        nested_index=c_order_index, array_shape=listex.shape
    )
    f_order_index = calculate_nested_index_f_order(
        flat_index=l, array_shape=listex.shape
    )
    flatindex2 = calculate_flat_index_f(
        nested_index=f_order_index, array_shape=listex.shape
    )
    from_c_to_f = convert_c_to_f_index(c_index=c_order_index, array_shape=listex.shape)
    from_f_to_c = convert_f_to_c_index(f_index=f_order_index, array_shape=listex.shape)
    print(f"values/flat index c: {value2}")
    print(f"values/flat index c_order_index: {c_order_index}")

    print(f"values/flat index flatindex1: {flatindex1}")
    print(f"values/flat index f: {value}")
    print(f"values/flat index f_order_index: {f_order_index}")
    print(f"values/flat index flatindex2: {flatindex2}")
    print("00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
    print(f"values/flat index from_c_to_f: {from_c_to_f}")
    print(f"values/flat index from_f_to_c: {from_f_to_c}")
    print(
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    )

# ......
# values/flat index c: 10
# values/flat index c_order_index: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
# values/flat index flatindex1: 10
# values/flat index f: 24
# values/flat index f_order_index: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# values/flat index flatindex2: 24
# 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
# values/flat index from_c_to_f: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# values/flat index from_f_to_c: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# values/flat index c: 11
# values/flat index c_order_index: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
# values/flat index flatindex1: 11
# values/flat index f: 144
# values/flat index f_order_index: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# values/flat index flatindex2: 144
# 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
# values/flat index from_c_to_f: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# values/flat index from_f_to_c: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# ......
```